# How do you stop the conversion from character to entity in HTML contenteditable="true" boxes?

Tags: html

I'm using a `contentEditable="TRUE"` `div` element and it keeps converting `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and it's getting so annoying.

Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: get the element.textContent and set it back to the element innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

It does not convert “<” and “>”. They get inserted into the DOM as such. If you serialize the element, then they get converted, just like any other text content. Demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Edit</title>
<div id=edit contenteditable style="border: solid"></div>
<input type=button value=Show onclick=show()>
<script>
function show() {
  var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
  console.log(edit.textContent);
  console.log(edit.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

If you test with, say, `a < b > c`, then the console output is

```
a < b > c
a &lt; b &gt; c
```

Comment: Well, I'm looking for something to **prevent** it from converting `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I want it to stay that way.
What we don't want:
`<b>` to `&lt;b&gt;`|
What we want:
`<b>` to `<b>`| Is there any way?

Comment: I've tested it in the real-time [HTML editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com) and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why have you accepted the answer if “it doesn’t seem to work”? There is no conversion that you need to prevent; the text node (and the `textContent` property) contains the data entered, as such. When you *want* to do the conversion, you use `innerHTML` (directly or indirectly).